# When I buy stocks, I lose the money I paid but I don't get the stocks. Why?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm playing Grand Theft Auto V on PS4 with autosave on. When I buy stocks, I lose the money I paid but I don't get the stocks. Please help me. I have not tried anything because I don't know what to do; maybe sometime it will work. If you help me that would be very nice of you. (Sorry if bad English.)